# If $a,b,c,d$ represent $4$ positive integers such that $b-a=d-c$ and $a<b<c<d$ then $bc>ad$ always

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a,b,c,d$ represent $4$ positive integers such that $b-a=d-c$ and $a<b<c<d $

the Geometric mean of $b$ and $c$ is always larger than the GM of $a$ and $d$

Is there any such theorem?

Comment: The claim you are making is true.  Have you tried to prove it?

Comment: if b-a=d-c=x a positive integer then ad=a(c+x)=ac+ax and bc=(a+x)c=ac+cx and subtracting bc-ad= ac+cx-ac-ax=(c-a)x>0

Comment: Good.  Observe that $bc - ad = cx - ax = (c - a)x$, where $c - a$ and $x$ are positive numbers, which implies that $bc > ad$.

Comment: so the order of b and c doesn't really matter?

Comment: The proof is based on the hypothesis that $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers such that $a < b < c < d$.

Comment: a<c<b<d would work too as long as b-a=d-c

Comment: That is correct since \begin{align*} bc - ad & = c(a + x) - a(c + x)\\ & = ac + cx - ac - ax\\ & = cx - ax\\ & = (c - a)x\end{align*} is the product of two positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$(c-a)(d-c) \geq 0$

$(d-c)(c) + a(c-d) \geq 0$

$(b-a)(c)+a(c-d) \geq 0$

$bc-ad  \geq 0$

$ bc \geq ad$

$ \sqrt{bc} \geq \sqrt{ad}$

The steps are reversible. I think.

Lazy to change: $\geq \to >$